# Spring boot JPA, Postgres: InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException doing a simple select

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

The DB has 2 users defined : usr and adm
Running the query below from the application under the usr one would throw an `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException`, while it will work well using the adm user.

Strangely, from pgAdmin, running under both users, this query works.

Any ideas ?

**Query**

```sql
SELECT foo FROM X where bar is not null
```

**Stacktrace**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: 
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: 
could not extract ResultSet
```

Note

Checked already the query with `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`.
The grammar is correct, and the exact same java code is executed for both users.

Comment: attach full stacktrace. This error can be caused by wrong field or table name, but answer is next lines of log

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed.

For those facing the same issue, the problem was simply due to unsufficient rights given to usr and that `?sslmode=require` needed to be appended at the end of the JDBC URL

```
jdbc:postgresql://XX:5432/YY?sslmode=require
```

The logs aren't helpful here and limited to what was given in the initial post